# Docker Container must be ran on elevated privelidges

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker container for my node.js application. When I run the docker desktop in administrator and Powershell in Administrator I get the following error.

> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1> FROM node:12
> At line:1 char:1
> + FROM node:12
> + ~~~~
> The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
> + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReservedKeywordNotAllowed
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1>
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1> # Create app directory
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1> WORKDIR /usr/src/app
> WORKDIR : The term 'WORKDIR' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
> + WORKDIR /usr/src/app
> + ~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (WORKDIR:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1>
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1> # Install app dependencies
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1> # A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1> # where available (npm@5+)
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1> COPY package*.json ./
> COPY : Cannot overwrite the item
> C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1\package-lock.json with itself.
> At line:1 char:1
> + COPY package*.json ./
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\User\N...ckage-lock.json:String)
> [Copy-Item], IOException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> CopyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
> COPY : Cannot overwrite the item
> C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1\package.json with itself.
> At line:1 char:1
> + COPY package*.json ./
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\User\N...p1\package.json:String)    [Copy-Item], IOException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> CopyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1>
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1> RUN npm install
> RUN : The term 'RUN' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
> spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
> and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
> + RUN npm install
> + ~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (RUN:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1> # If you are building your code
> for production
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1> # RUN npm ci --only=production
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1>
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1> # Bundle app source
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1> COPY . .
> COPY : Cannot overwrite the item C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1 with
> itself.
> At line:1 char:1
> + COPY . .
> + ~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\User\N...1\NodejsWebApp1:String)
> [Copy-Item], IOException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> CopyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1>
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1> EXPOSE 3000
> EXPOSE : The term 'EXPOSE' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
> script file, or operable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
> is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
> + EXPOSE 3000
> + ~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (EXPOSE:String) [],
> CommandNotFoundException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
> PS C:\Users\User\NodejsWebApp1\NodejsWebApp1> CMD [ "node", "server.js"
> ]ect.:ect.:

Sorry about the mess of error, but that is what it was printing out!
The command I was running was

```
docker build -t name .
```

This is my DockerFile

```
FROM node:12
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install 

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Should I maybe try doing this in Linux as I am currently running Windows 10, would this be a greater option.
Many thanks. Jeff

Comment: Have you tried.... sudo docker build -t name .

Comment: Hello thank you for your response, when I run Sudo it says unknown command. I don’t think Sudo is a windows command?

Comment: can you try a different workdir? e.g. /opt

Comment: I get a different eerror during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=DockerFile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=whiteboard&target=&ulimits=null&version=1: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.rror now : `

Comment: Try to execute docker build from git bash instead of powershell.